# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: vim-windows, microsoft-windows, plugin-python-mode

I am new to vim. As much as I love it, there seem to be a lot of bugs or errors every time I try doing something.

I am unable to run the plugin "browserlink.vim" (https://github.com/jaxbot/browserlink.vim). It shows the following error:

`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec 
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

I have searched for fixing but I don't understand exactly what to do from the documentation found on StackOverflow and Github issues. For instance, when running the command `:py print(1)` it throws the error `E887: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python's site module could not be loaded`.

My vim version is 8.0 and the python version I have installed is 3.6.5 (64bits) and I use Windows 10. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Add an environment variable "PYTHONPATH" which points to the installation location of Python and restart the editor.

Comment: Welcome to our site! It would be useful for future reader to explain with a bit more details why this variable is necessary and why it should solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same thing, specifically with Anaconda Python. It appears to be a recent change to some of their DLLs and it has nothing to do with Vim.

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10660

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I came across recently but in different situation.
My project needed to use anaconda3, so I used conda to create a virtual env.
But when I coded in Vim, lots of my plugins could not work. Bummer.
My Vim81 support python/python3 assured by the "+python-dyn/+python3-dyn" in `:ver` report.

The problem is: vim needs to find the "right" pythonXX.dll.

Which is the "right" one? It also in the `:ver` report (as mine): `"-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL = 'PYTHON37.DLL"`

So I need the python37.dll. The python3.7 was shipped with Anaconda3, how lucky I was!

I tried to set this (the `set pythonthreedll=` belongs to _vimrc):

```
set pythonthreedll=c:\\path\\to\\Ananconda3\\python37.dll
```

Not work. So I tried with:

```
set pythonthreedll=c:\\path\\to\\Ananconda3\\envs\\My-Virtural-env\\python37.dll
```

And I got another error.

I finally installed an individual python3.7 (from Python.com), added its root dir and the subdir 'Scripts' (such as `c:\\User\\python\\python37\\Scripts`) to the system path. I tried to set the 'pythonthreedll' again with newly installed python3.7:

```
set pythonthreedll=c:\\path\\to\\My-installed-Python-root-dir\\python37.dll
```

and it works! In vim, I tried `:py3 print(1)`.

It should return a '1' to you. It meant that vim found the python (it prefered).

I use python3, but python2 might work in the same manner.